# How to configure GlassFish connection pool in order to work with multiple Databases?

Tags: glassfish, connection-pooling

Well, My WebApp uses several databases and I'm trying to use GlassFish connection pool to manage the connections, but I've found configuration examples that use only one database.

So, what should I do? Create as many connection pools as databases I'm using or is there a way to configure a pool with multiple databases?

Answer (score 1):

A connection pool connects to only one database (or cluster), so if you need access to different data stores you will need to set up several connection pools. One for each data store.